# Unable to cast object of type 'Parent' to type 'Child'

Tags: c#, casting, downcast

I was trying to cast my parent into my child (aka Down casting). Below is the example for the same:

```
public class Parent
{
    public void ParentMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In Parent Method");
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public void ParentMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In Child Method");
    }
}
```

I get no compile time error, however when I execute my below code, I get the exception like this **Unable to cast object of type 'Parent' to type 'Child'.**

```
Child obj2 = (Child)new Parent();
obj2.ParentMethod();
```

Please help me in getting the below questions answer:

1. How to resolve this exception.
2. Is this is a good way to explain Up/Down casting.
3. Which ParentMethod will be called by complier, in this example i.e. of Parent class or of Child class.

Comment: See duplicate, especially: _"subclasses provide more than base classes - where does this "more" come from?"_

Comment: An instance of `Parent` isn't an instance of `Child`. This is like saying `string s = (string)new object();`

Comment: @Lee or like saying `var animal = new Animal(); var dog = (Dog)animal;`. You cannot solve this problem by casting alone.